# Node.js Promises with Q :: Q.ninvoke chains

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I'm trying to narrow down the potential causes of memory issues I'm having with my node.js server. One part of the code that I've always been a bit uncomfortable with is my use of Q promises.

Here's what my basic structure looks like:

```
var Q = require('q');
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(somedata, callback) {
    var res = [];// will contain the results of each function call

    Q.ninvoke(this, 'doSomethingElse', 'hello!')
    .then((function(result){
        res.push(result);
        return Q.ninvoke(this.someobject, 'someFunction', somedata);
    }).bind(this))
    .then((function(result){
        res.push(result);
        callback(null, res);// Returns both result objects, in an array
    }).bind(this))
    .fail(callback)
    .done();
}
```

Does this seem logical?

What if the doSomethingElse function also employs promises? Is everything scoped properly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks pretty solid to me. There's no problem with `this.doSomethingElse` using promises, as long as it exposes a Node.js callback API (e.g. via `nodeify`; see recently-updated [API reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference)).

--

That said, I would rewrite your function as follows:

```
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(somedata, callback) {
    return Q.all([
        Q.ninvoke(this, 'doSomethingElse', 'hello!'),
        Q.ninvoke(this.someobject, 'someFunction', somedata)
    ]).nodeify(callback);
};
```

if you were in a case where the second function depended on the result of the first, unlike the one given here, I'd do

```
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(somedata, callback) {
    return Q.ninvoke(this, 'doSomethingElse', 'hello!').then(function (result) {
      return Q.invoke(this.someobject, 'someFunction', result);
    }.bind(this))
    .nodeify(callback);
};
```

or maybe

```
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(somedata, callback) {
    var doSomethingElse = Q.nfbind(this.doSomethingElse.bind(this));
    var someFunction = Q.nfbind(this.someobject.someFunction.bind(this.someobject));

    return doSomethingElse('hello!').then(someFunction).nodeify(callback);
};
```

--

More generally: we've recently been working on Q performance and memory, with the results mostly in the unreleased master branch. In particular:

- 0.8.11 [fixed a rather horrible memory leak](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/111) related to long stack traces
- Master [fixes a small memory leak with `Q.reject`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/148)
- Master no longer uses `Object.freeze`, which is [slow in V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1858)
- Master adds the ability to [turn off long stack traces](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#long-stack-traces).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Q.all implies asynchonous execution. I did not explicitly state in my example that I need to run sequentially, but typically my 2nd function relies upon the results of the 1st function. This being the case, is my example the "best way?" Or is there something better?

Comment: Promises inherently have asynchronous execution, so I'm not sure what you mean.

For second functions that rely on the result of the first, `then` is indeed the correct choice. Example included.